# Parkade Fire - Vancouver hockey riot. 

Tags: field-recording

Anybody in Vancouver get the hockey riots on tape?
I'd love to hear my country's self respect flushing itself down the toilet.

Comment: ditto!  that would rock.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad I wasn't downtown recording the mess that went on. Yes I had that urge to be capturing those sounds. But if I was I would have been one more person being part of the problem. People had gone down there with the express intent to riot and cause damage. Lots of them where encouraged by everyone documenting their idiocy. Being someone who lives in the city it's hard to separate the stupidity of what just went on with the possible sounds that may have happened during it.

Answer (score 1):

My image of Canada is shaken.  I thought you guys were supposed to be the polite ones and Bostonites were the thugs?  Say it aint so. Next you're gonna tell me your health care's not that good either?

Comment: The healthcare system is fine, really, but in this country, hockey turns everyone into a gibbering ape. 

Comment: Zealotry leads inexorably to stupidity, of any type, be it religion, hockey, or Mac vs. PC.

Comment: In India we kill each other over Cricket.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that if I was back in Canada, I would have been downtown recording the insanity. It also saddens me being a fellow Canadian that we could people stoop to such a level of violence for the rest of the world to see. But it must have sounded amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, with all this sound, who has time for watching Hockey? Or participating in riots. Or a good night's sleep...

I have absolutely no interest in Hockey or any sport. I've only lived in Vancouver a year but seeing the images of the fights and burning cars and smashed windows was sickening, I actually felt ill, and very sad. The riot may have happened no matter what the outcome of the game was.

I'm sure someone had their audio gear ready, I wouldn't have risked it personally. Some of the media was attacked and cameras were destroyed.

Comment: Hey, I was in Van yesterday, but haven't checked in here in a while.  We coulda met up or something.  Dang.

Comment: Dang indeed. Give me a call next time (my # should be easy to find) if you want to meet up. Same goes for anyone else that wants to in the Vancouver area.

Answer (score 1):

I've started reaching out to a few of the people that posted videos on vimeo.  watching that stuff is both incredibly sad and a little overwhelming.

I imagine that if I was in Vancouver at the time I'd probably be crazy enough to try to run out there and catch some sounds (don't tell my wife), but it seems like there were more than a couple of people out there with dslr rigs and probably at least an H4 to record with.

there are certain things that you really just can't fake.  the crowds yelling and chanting, the "ooohhh" reaction that goes up when something explodes, the laughing and crying and fighting and cursing.

Crazy times friends.